# How can changes to a property within an instance of a child object be communicated to the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am having a databinding/view refresh issue.  When the TotalTaskCount property of my Worklist class changes because it is not being reflected in my view (view still displays old value in column).

My data is structured similar to this:

[image]

The view containing a datagrid has its ItemSource property bound to a property in the view-model as follows:

```
    <DataContext="{Binding DashBoardVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTeamToManage.Worklists}"
              AutoGenerateColumns = "true"/>
```

The View-Model is something like this:

```
    public class DashBoardViewModel
    {
             Observable Collection <Worklist> TeamWorklists = new ObservableCollection <Worklist>();

             //Bound to ItemSource of the datagrid
             public TeamWorkload SelectedTeamToManage
             {
                get { return _selectedTeamToManage; }
                set 
                { 
                     _selectedTeamToManage = value;
                     RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTeamToManage");
                }
             }
     }
```

The TeamWorkload class looks like this:

```
public class TeamWorkload
{
     public string TeamName
     {
         get { return _teamName; }
         set { _teamName = value; }
     }

     public ObservableCollection<Worklist> WorkLists
     {
          get { return _teamWorkLists; }
          set 
          { 
            _teamWorkLists = value;             
          }
     }
}
```

And the Worklist class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and looks like this:

```
public Class Worklist
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     [DisplayName("Total Tasks Count")]
     public int TotalTasksCount
     {
        get { return _totalTasksCount; }
        set 
        { 
           _totalTasksCount = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalTasksCount");
        }
     }

     private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
     {
        var propChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propChanged != null)
        {
             propChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
     }
}
```

I just don't know how to get the viewmodel to be aware of the change within the TeamWorkload observable collection and update the databindings.  I have googled everything I can find regarding nested properties, collectionchanged events, bubbling property changed events but I can't see how to implement any of the example code I am finding in my solution.  I am not even sure if this is my issue but it's my best guess.  Any hints would be deeply appreciated as I am still relatively new to both .NET, MVVM, and C#.

Comment: Have you tried looking into GlobalPropertyChanged event ?

Comment: Thanks Rahul - I hadn't.  I will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a `PropertyChanged` event is not the same as actually implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Change

```
public class Worklist
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ...
}
```

to

```
public class Worklist : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ...
}
```

---

In order to avoid this error, you may derive all your view model classes from a common base class like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Clemens,  I can't believe I missed that!  That did the trick.  Thanks a million!

Comment: If you have more than one view model class, you may create a common base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has a protected NotifyPropertyChanged method.